# OutOfMemoryError: Reading large XML by InvokeScriptedProcessor and groovy reading from stream, different behavior for 2GB and 11GB file

Tags: xml, apache-nifi

I am using InvokeScriptedProcessor, Groovy to read large XML in stream and updating flowfile.
Nifi is running with 10GB max heap in docker container.

While testing with 2.5 GB XML, docker stat memory for nifi is around 1GB. However in case of 11GB file nifi is reporting OutOfMemoryError. While monitoring docker stat, I can see memory is keep on increasing for 11GB XML file but incase of 2GB XML File memory stays at 1GB

I am trying to uderstand how to determine the nifi max heap requirement in case of 11GB, if 2GB file is getting completed by using 1 GB nifi memory then 11GB file should take 6 to 7GB memory.

What are the options here to optimize code, I want to avoid batching of these files since these are complex XML file and have recursive orgranization of tags.

```
 try {
     flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { inputStream, outputStream ->
        InputStreamReader br = new InputStreamReader(inputStream)
        br.eachLine { line ->
            if (ln == 0) {
                ln++
                outputStream.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            } else {
                if (matcher.size() > 0) {
                    vsDataTypeFound = matcher.getAt(0)[1]
                    outputStream.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                } else if (mMEOpen.size() > 0) {
                }
            } as StreamCallback)
            if (failed.get()) {
                session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
            } else {
                session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
                FlowFile rncCSVFlowFile = session . create ()
            }

            session.commit()
```

I expect that using stream for 11GB XML file nifi memory should not be increasing even beyond 10GB which is nifi heap

Comment: Are you sure the XML has line breaks? If it doesn't then the first line could be the entire 11 GB content.

Comment: Thanks @BryanBende, I didn't looked into original file, yes the XML is not having line breaks properly, head -n 1 is huge.

Comment: new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), bufferSize);

Comment: What about a BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), bufferSize); where fine tune the bufferSize? also make sure you close the stream reader inside a try finally block?

Comment: I have used SAX to pretty print the large XML, only added newline and tab not other operations, nifi mmory was obeserved approx 1GB and then used scanner for string related operation in another processor, this processor also completed usinf approx 1GB nifi memory